# Using MagicalRecord - Not able to fetch data appropriately from pre-loaded .sqlite file

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to get some info out of my sqlite database with magical record.
It should be noted - this app worked prior to iOS9 without any issues.  Since iOS9 it crashes so I am reworking it.  I installed cocoapods and installed MagicalRecord via pods (which worked fine).

In my AppDelegate file I preload the DB with data from an .sqlite file I have and setup the CoreData stack using MagicalRecord.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[self copyDefaultStoreIfNecessary];
    //Copy the preloaded DB to the default path of the application's DB (REQUIRED)
    NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSURL *documentPath = [paths lastObject];
    NSURL *storeURL = [documentPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Trips_54Miles.sqlite"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path] ]) {
        NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Trips_54Miles" ofType:@"sqlite" ]];
        NSError *err = nil;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err]){
            NSLog(@"Error:  Unable to copy preloaded db.");
        }
    }
    //Setup Magical Record with the CoreData Stack
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"Trips_54Miles.sqlite"];
    NSArray *schools = [MetaMiles MR_findAllSortedBy:@"beg_school" ascending:YES];
    NSLog(@"Default Array: %@", schools);
    return YES;
}
```

The array 'schools', always shows up in the log like this:

'Default Array: ( )'

Showing no entries.

Curious as to why.  I have checked the .sqlite file I'm loading and it has all appropriate information loaded.

Any ideas on where I should be headed to pull the information would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `copyDefaultStoreIfNecessary` is failing to copy the file? It's the most obvious potential problem in your code.

Comment: I have it set to Log a message if it fails to copy the file - I do not see the failure message in console.

Comment: Does it copy the SQLite journal files or just the main SQLite file?

Comment: I believe it just copies the main SQLite file: you can see the copyDefaultStoreIfNecessary here: https://github.com/PushpinDesigns/54Miles/blob/dev/54%20Miles/ML54AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you created your pre-loaded SQLite file, it's very likely that there are three files rather than just one-- the main `.sqlite` file plus two others, `.sqlite-wal` and `.sqlite-shm`. If this is the case, most or all of the data will be in those files. Copying just the `.sqlite` file will, in effect, remove all of the data while keeping the data model intact. So you can still open the file, but there's nothing to fetch.

You would need to copy those files in order to keep the data intact.

Comment: It's been quite some time (almost 2 years) since I wrote this app.  What I do know is that there is only one .sqlite file (historically and currently).  I can view the .sqlite file with SQLite Database Browser and see all appropriate information.

Comment: If there's only one file, fine, but viewing it with SQLite Database Browser isn't relevant-- it would use the journal files if they were present.

Comment: I've never had to use the journal files before?  This app worked for a couple of years - I've never had to deal with or worry about journal files (through my own admission - I don't know what those are); so I'm left with the impression that journal files are not the appropriate answer here.

Comment: Newer versions of iOS use different journaling schemes, so the extra files haven't always been present. If the **are** present then they're absolutely critical, but if they don't exist then obviously they don't matter.

Comment: I understand.  Unfortunately they are not present, so I'll keep digging around.  Thank you for your help!